# Having issues using PLayerPrefs to save an FPS counter on load via a toggle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I am generally confused with this. Basically I have a toggle button that lets you enable or disable UI elements. In this case it's the text that displays your FPS (aka an FPS counter). It works except for the fact that it doesn't save on scene change.

I tried using PlayerPrefs to save these types of things. It worked with my volume slider except the thing is, that's a float so it makes things a lot easier. But there is nothing regarding bool values for PlayerPrefs unless you do some tinkering to somehow make it work with other functions.

I tried using different methods and it doesn't seem to save my option for my FPS counter, here's my code, I would appreciate the help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
 
public class Options : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Toggle flowerCanvasToggle;
 
    public Canvas flowerCanvas;
 
    public TMP_Text Timer;
 
    public Toggle timerToggle;
 
    public TMP_Text fpstextright;
 
    public TMP_Text fpstextbottomright;
 
    public TMP_Text fpstextbottomleft;
 
    public Toggle fpstogglebottomleft;
 
    public Toggle fpstogglebottomright;
 
    public Toggle fpstoggleright;
 
    public Toggle fpstoggle;
 
    public TMP_Text fpstext;
 
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
 
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
 
    public float OverallVolume;
 
    public Slider volumeSlider;
 
    Resolution[] resolutions;
 
    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Volume"))
        {
            volumeSlider.GetComponent<Slider>().value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Volume");
        }
 
        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
 
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();
 
        List<string> options = new List<string>();
 
 
        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + "x" + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);
 
            if (resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width && resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }
 
        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();
    }
 
    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
        Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
    }
 
    public void SetVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
        audioMixer.GetFloat("Volume", out OverallVolume);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
 
 
    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }
 
    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;
    }
    public void FPSCounter(bool isFPSOn)
    {
        fpstoggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();
    }
 
    public void FPSOtherThings()
    {
        bool IsOn = false;
 
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsOn") == 1)
        {
            IsOn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsOn = false;
        }
        fpstoggle.isOn = IsOn;
    }
    public void FPSContinued(Toggle change)
    {
       
 
        if (fpstoggle.isOn)
        {
            fpstext.enabled = true;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsOn", 1);
        }
        else
        {
            fpstext.enabled = false;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsOn", 0);
        }
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
 
    public void TimerOnorOff(bool isTimerOn)
    {
        timerToggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();
    }
 
    int boolToInt(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
 
    bool intToBool(int val)
    {
        if(val != 0) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
    public void TimerContinued(Toggle change)
    {
     
       
       
        if (timerToggle.isOn)
        {
            Timer.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Timer.enabled = false;
        }
    }
    public void FlowersOnorOff(bool flowersIsOn)
    {
        flowerCanvasToggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();
    }
    public void FlowersContinued(Toggle change)
    {
        if (flowerCanvasToggle.isOn)
        {
            flowerCanvas.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            flowerCanvas.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

And for the record I have tried the method where you convert bool to float and that has failed as well, I have no idea what needs to be done.

Comment: `FPSContinued` should save it, and `FPSOtherThings` should read it back. It isn't shown how or if you actually call those functions. You're ignoring the parameter in the first function and the second doesn't need the else, it defaults to false already.